# Pagedlist not redirecting to next pages when clicked?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

It correctly shows the number of pages, as well as the supposedly number of records per page which is 10. However, when I click page x it does not redirect to the next page of records.

I have used this code on a previous project and it works just fine. Is there anything I may have missed?

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        try
        {
            int intPage = 1;
            int intPageSize = 10;
            int intTotalPageCount = 0;

            List<Announcement> col_Announcement = new List<Announcement>();
            int intSkip = (intPage - 1) * intPageSize;

            intTotalPageCount = db.Announcements.Count();

            var result = db.Announcements
                .Take(intPageSize)
                .ToList();

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Announcement objAnnouncement = new Announcement();
                objAnnouncement.AnnouncementDate = item.AnnouncementDate;
                objAnnouncement.AnnouncementTitle = item.AnnouncementTitle;
                objAnnouncement.AnnouncementBody = item.AnnouncementBody;

                col_Announcement.Add(objAnnouncement);
            }

            // Set the number of pages
            var _AnnouncementAsIPagedList =
                new StaticPagedList<Announcement>
                (
                    col_Announcement, intPage, intPageSize, intTotalPageCount
                    );

            return View(_AnnouncementAsIPagedList);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error: " + ex);
            List<Announcement> col_Announcement = new List<Announcement>();

            return View(col_Announcement.ToPagedList(1, 25));

        }
    }
```

My View:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Test.Models.Announcement>
@using PagedList.Mvc;

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Announcements</h2>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Date Posted
            </th>
            <th>
                Title
            </th>
            <th>
                Body
            </th>

        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AnnouncementDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AnnouncementTitle)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AnnouncementBody)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new {page}))
</div>
```

Comment: you need to use **.Skip** to skip first x-1 pages.

Comment: You first use `.Skip()` and `.Take()` to limit the result to the first 10 items, and then use `StaticPagedList()` which internally uses `.Skip()` and `,Take()` which makes no sense. And to then use a loop to generate another identical collection makes even less sense. And you never even use the value of `page` which is sent to the method - you only ever get the first 10 records so you just keep returning the same set of 10 records each time

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip some records before you take the records

```
int intSkip = (page - 1) * intPageSize;
var result = db.Announcements
            .Skip(intSkip)
            .Take(intPageSize)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: I added .OrderBy(x => x.AnnouncementDate), the records are displayed again but the page is not working still

Comment: Check the updated answer. You need to use page while calculating skip pahe